# Django template variables rendered after 403

Tags: python, django

I have an HTML template which will render button depending on context variable.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit">{{ number }}</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

After passing "if" check for numbers greater than 400, the function should return response 403 and stop. But in my case it only ignores a template and still renders a context variable.

```py
def run_script(request, number):
    if number > 400:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    context = {'number': number}
    return render(request, "mainapp/number.html", context)
```

The only solution I found is so set the rendered value to null in the "if" statement

```py
if number > 400:
        number = None
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

This way I get proper response 403, but I dont like this method since it requires changing every variable, when multiple provided and doesn't look like a proper implementation.
Any suggestion how to properly stop execution on response 403?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>ChatGPT</strike> suggested using

```py
return HttpResponse(content_type='text/html', content=render_to_string('mainapp/number.html', context))
```

As this is currently working, I'm gonna stick to that, but I'm not implying that is perfect solution due to it's source.

Comment: Right now, answer produced by chatGPT are not permitted in StackOverflow. Check [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1](this page) for further details.

Comment: @FabioL thanks mr. nerd, I already know that. This is why I specified